# What is the name of this practice when a page loads?

Tags: loading, page-layout, placeholder, content-loading

It seems that some basic elements take their position quite quickly:

[image]

and then others follow to form the final page:

[image]

## update (Apr 2018)

I've noticed that youtube is also doing this...

[image]

Comment: Its called annoying the crap out of your user because your app loads terribly slow. While it mitigates the loading times, fast loading is crucial for user retention. If you need to resort to this, something is wrong.

Comment: @Polygnome fast loading is of course important, but using these kinds of graphical tricks can often make loading seem significantly faster.  And there are real limits to how fast you can actually load in many cases.

Comment: @Polygnome I would disagree. If you have to load a large volume of content, such as in Facebook's case (videos, images, ads), it's better for the user to look at something while it loads than a blank screen.

Comment: @Alan Yes, its is *better* then looking at a blank screen. But it is still annoying as hell. Look at googles research regarding this topic, shaving even a few fractions of a second off your loading time can increase user retention *drastically* - that is why Google goes through great length to make their sites load fast. Some sites - and Facebook is one of them - are just bloated like hell, but they can get away with that because they are already market leader.

Comment: @Polygnome today I've noticed that youtube is also using this practice...

Comment: @tgogos There is a difference - they show the whole structure, first, instead of a nondescript loading screen. Loading big images later (or low res first, then high res) has always been a good practice, especially for sites with lots of big images. Nothing flies around on the screen during loading on YT, all elements are there directly and then just get flipped to actual content. And I'm pretty sure they *know* that loading instantly would still be better, but can't get it faster. Its still just a workaround for a bottleneck.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's called a **content placeholder** or **skeleton screens**.  This is a great way to **focus attention** on progress and **content being loaded** instead of wait times while the whole app is loading.

---

**About Skeleton screens**

Apple have incorporated skeleton screens into its iOS Human Interface Guidelines, calling it "launch images." It recommends showing an outline of the initial application screen without text or any graphical elements that may change.

[image]

**About content placeholder :**

Facebook App (and some other mobile app) made this strategy famous, making users think their apps loads faster.

### [image]

---

Sources :

- https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/
- https://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1797
- https://uxplanet.org/how-to-make-users-think-your-app-loads-faster-24052fe307bf
- https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-speed-up-your-ux-with-skeleton-screens/

Comment: Hey ! I Added skeleton-screen and content-loading to your question

Comment: If those are essentially synonyms why add both tags?

Comment: They are not. Skeleton refer to UI elements loaded before content, placeholders are dummy contents displayed while real content is loading.

Comment: The real question is, do we really need those tags?

Comment: Aren't they helpfull for search ? Also, question author asked for it